# Change image with javascript mouse position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, scroll, mouseevent

I am trying to achieve an effect like what is shown on this site: https://ca.warbyparker.com/eyeglasses/women/louise/elderflower-crystal

When you move your mouse position (or thumb for mobile) the image shown will change depending on the horizontal position of the mouse.

I have been trying to get it to work in react and I am having some trouble, even with getting a working jquery or vanilla javascript solution I can't seem to get it.

What i've got so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="product-hero">

        <div class="hero-container">
          <img class="product-hero-image left" src="http://placehold.it/708x1282/000000?text=%3C%E2%80%93+left" alt="" />
          <img class="product-hero-image middle" src="http://placehold.it/708x1282/000000?text=middle" alt="" />
          <img class="product-hero-image right" src="http://placehold.it/708x1282/000000?text=right+--%3E" alt="" />

        </div>
      </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).mousemove(getMousePosition);

    function getMousePosition(event) {
      let imageTop = $('.product-hero-image').offset().top;
      let imageLeft = $('.product-hero-image').offset().left;
      let imageBottom = imageTop + $('.product-hero-image').height();
      let imageRight = imageLeft + $('.product-hero-image').width();

      var mouseX = event.pageX;
      var mouseY = event.pageY;

      if (mouseX > imageLeft && mouseX < imageRight && mouseY < imageTop) {
        $('.product-hero-image.middle').toggle();
        console.log('top right');
      } else if (mouseX < imageLeft && mouseY < imageTop) {
        $('.product-hero-image.left').toggle();
        console.log('top left');
      } else if (mouseX < imageLeft && mouseY > imageTop && mouseY < imageBottom) {
        $('.product-hero-image.left').toggle();
        console.log('bottom left');
      } else if (mouseX < imageLeft && mouseY > imageBottom) {
        $('.product-hero-image.left').toggle();
        console.log('left');
      } else if (mouseX > imageLeft && mouseX < imageRight && mouseY > imageBottom) {
        $('.product-hero-image.middle').toggle();
        console.log('middle');
      } else if (mouseX > imageRight && mouseY > imageBottom) {
        $('.product-hero-image.right').toggle();
        console.log('right');
      } else if (mouseX > imageRight && mouseY > imageTop && mouseY < imageBottom) {
        $('.product-hero-image.right').toggle();
        console.log('bottom right');
      } else if (mouseX > imageRight && mouseY < imageTop) {
        $('.product-hero-image.right').toggle();
        console.log('top right');
      } else {
        $('.product-hero-image.middle').toggle();
        console.log('middle');
      }
    }

    $('.product-hero-image').css('z-index', '0');
```

https://codepen.io/H0BB5/pen/rwqwPP

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did too much logic decisions in your code.

You have to get things easier :D. I did a fork of your code and I simplify it and it works. Check [this](https://codepen.io/henriquebertoldi/pen/weYqwp) out.

```
$(".product-hero").mousemove(getMousePosition);

function getMousePosition(event) {
  let elementVisible = $('.product-hero-image:visible');
  let imageTop = elementVisible.offset().top;
  let imageLeft = elementVisible.offset().left;
  let imageBottom = imageTop + elementVisible.height();
  let imageRight = imageLeft + elementVisible.width();

  var mouseX = event.pageX;
  var mouseY = event.pageY;

  if (mouseY < imageTop || mouseY > imageBottom) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(mouseY);
  elementVisible.hide();

  if (mouseX > imageLeft && mouseX < imageRight){
    $('.product-hero-image.middle').show();
  }
  else if (mouseX < imageLeft) {
    $('.product-hero-image.left').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.product-hero-image.right').show();
  }
}

$('.product-hero-image').css('z-index', '0');
```

Comment: YES! 
Thanks Henrique, I really do need to get things easier, haha. 
Do you know how I would be able to get it like the site linked above? Meaning adding more images, rather than just 3 having it cycle through 7-10.

Comment: Yes, just using some Math and css. To facilitate, make the wrapper div width fill 100% of screen and attach the mousemove listener in this wrapper div. So all the rest is math. I did a new pen, you can adding more imagem as you wish, just change the variable imageCount. 
https://codepen.io/henriquebertoldi/pen/ZyqXGW